# bound must be positive

Tags: java, bukkit

Here is the error I keep on getting, which I understand, but can't fix, because I don't know what the problem is.

```
[14:25:50 ERROR]: Could not pass event BlockBreakEvent to SurgeGlowstone v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:297) ~[custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:513) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:498) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerInteractManager.breakBlock(PlayerInteractManager.java:264) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerInteractManager.dig(PlayerInteractManager.java:118) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:569) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInBlockDig.a(PacketPlayInBlockDig.java:41) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInBlockDig.handle(PacketPlayInBlockDig.java:65) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:189) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:103) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:801) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:286) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:651) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [custom.jar:git-PaperSpigot-a925999]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
        at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at com.surgehcf.listeners.PlayerListener.onBreak(PlayerListener.java:49) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
```

And here is my code:

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    // NOTE: This will (intentionally) not run as written so that folks
    // copy-pasting have to think about how to initialize their
    // Random instance.  Initialization of the Random instance is outside
    // the main scope of the question, but some decent options are to have
    // a field that is initialized once and then re-used as needed or to
    // use ThreadLocalRandom (if using at least Java 1.7).
    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
@EventHandler
public void onBreak(BlockBreakEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    Block b = e.getBlock();
    JsonBox bx = GlowstoneMountain.getInstance().getRegionAqui(b.getLocation());
    if (bx != null && b.getType() == Material.GLOWSTONE && b.getWorld().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("world_nether")) {
        b.getWorld().dropItemNaturally(b.getLocation(), new ItemStack(Material.GLOWSTONE_DUST,randInt(4,2)));
    }
}
```

I always do a random integer between 4 and 2. But, still it's saying the negation of what I want: an integer between 2 and 4, to get a random output.

Comment: The error really says it all. Check the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-): *"bound - the upper bound (exclusive). Must be positive."* - you're passing in values that lead to a negative bound value. You should prevent that by adding a safeguard in your method. For example, check what value is greater and use that as max, the other as min.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `randInt(2,4)`, not `randInt(4,2)`, to get number between `min` 2 and `max` 4 (inclusive)?

Comment: Why do you even have the bounds swapped? `randInt(4,2)` will leave you with `rand.nextInt(-1)`, which throws the exception. The arguments should be `randInt(2,4)`. Smaller number before bigger number is almost universally used for anything that represents a range or bounds of sorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the error (and how to fix it), check the [Java docs on Random's `nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-):

> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> bound - the upper bound (exclusive). Must be positive.
> ```
>
> **Throws:**
>
> ```
> IllegalArgumentException - if bound is not positive
> ```

However, `randInt(4,2)`, as you called your method, is exactly the wrong way round. It uses `4` as `min`, `2` as `max` and you hence end up with a negative bound (`-1`), leading to the exception.

I therefore suggest the following change to your method:

```
public static int randInt(int a, int b) {
    int min = Math.min(a, b);
    int max = Math.max(a, b);
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

**Explanation:**

Right now, you trust the user of your function to respect the order of arguments (`min, max` - not `max, min`). While you can do that, you just experienced how quickly that can get you into trouble, even if the user is you.

Therefore, adding a safeguard like above will lead to more robust code. Here, we just check which one of the two values is the [smaller](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) and which is the [bigger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) one, then use them accordingly.

Of course, you could also leave your method as is and simply change the call to `randInt(2,4)`.

**Note:**

It would still be possible for the user to get your method to break (throw an exception as above), but I will leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how - and how you can safeguard against it. :-)

Comment: @jakeyancey How about just fixing the call instead: `randInt(2,4)`

Comment: @Andreas that's the obvious fix, as already covered by [Jamal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825319/3316645). I did add a sentence on it for completeness sake, however.

Answer (score 3):

In the `onBreak()` method, inside the `if` statement, change this:

```
new ItemStack(Material.GLOWSTONE_DUST,randInt(4,2)));
```

to this:

```
new ItemStack(Material.GLOWSTONE_DUST,randInt(2,4)));
```

Right now you're trying to get a random integer with a maximum of 2 and a minimum of 4. That isn't possible. Change it to a maximum of 4 and a minimum of 2.

The parameter order for the `randInt()` function is `(min, max)`. Currently you're treating it like it's `(max, min)`.